# How to use slicers to choose columns in a table?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have a table with columns Product, Units, Price, Sales (Units*Price).

I want a slicer to switch between Units, Price, Sales, and display these in various visuals interchangeably.

So the slicer will have the options of Units, Price, Sales and when I choose one of these, the rest visuals should display the numbers accordingly.

I know I am supposed to create a custom slicer with some variables but I have not been able to find a good tutorial to tell me what I need to do step by step and how it works, i.e. how the information flows from the slicer choices to the rest of the report.

Can anyone explain please?

Thanks!